# Reproduce JS animation found on a site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tween

I've found this interactive page on a site:

http://www.urwhatupost.com/avocado

I'd love to re-create it changing images and something else. Inspecting the DOM I cannot find a js reference library.
I've noticed some basic css animation (translate3d) that loops changing parameters each time.

What should be, in your opinion, the best way to reproduce it from the ground? Is there some useful js library to take in consideration for this kind of develop?

Thanks!

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you ask more specific questions. What exactly do you want to do? What kind of animations do you want to make?

Comment: Hi, Nico. You're perfectly right. I has to be more specific: in this sense the best way is to start from the baseline. What is the best way to animate a div (in loop) changing dynamically the value of rotation every time the animation ends?

Comment: Hi @frankcecca, what they are doing is pretty straight forward, they set `translate3d` that only changes the y coordinates so the avocados move up and down, the `transition` they put on the avocados are qubic-bezier with random timing so the user wont anticipate it.